# Shortest super-path to complete multiple paths to vertices.

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I have a graph with multiple vertices. Let's say all vertices are connected to each other, and all edges are equal weight.

I have multiple directed paths I have to take across this graph, but I want to minimize the total number of edges I have to traverse to complete all these directed paths.

For example:

Path 1: A -> B -> C -> B

Path 2: B -> A -> C

Shortest super-path: A -> B -> A -> C -> B

**How can I develop an algorithm for finding the shortest super-path?**

I have considered using a Shortest Superstring algorithm, but the problem is that the vertices don't have to be strictly tangential (Shortest Superstring for the above would be ABCBAC).

This is a common problem in logistics for deliveries as well as board and video games with many multi-step quests.

Comment: What do you mean by a super-path? From context, I suspect it's a path that contains all your paths in some way, but it's hard to guess what notion of containment you intend.

Comment: A path that contains all the given paths, conserving their respective orders of vertices.

Comment: So it doesn't have to contain their edges as well? Would the path $A \to B \to C \to D \to E$ contain $A \to C \to E$?

Comment: Correct. A→B→C→D→E contains A→C→E

Comment: The problem is known as shortest common supersequence and is NP-hard https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence